# Springfox swaggerui -> change the default ui path for swagger ui for spring-mvc

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, swagger-ui, springfox

for spring-mvc the default swagger-ui path is /swagger-ui.html. Any to change it to different path?
the generated code comes with a config file SwaggerUiConfiguration. Anyway to change it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible if you want to use springfox-swagger-ui.

You could manually copy the swagger ui resources and rename the file as you see fit.

Comment: By any chance, is this feature available now?